# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 90000 into shape (1,28,28,1)

Tags: python, opencv

How to solve this problem ? i am unable to find the solution.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    roi = frame[100:400, 320:620]
    cv2.imshow('roi', roi)
    roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.resize(roi, (28,28), interpolation= cv2.INTER_AREA)
    
    cv2.imshow('roi scaled and gray', roi)
    copy = frame.copy()
    
    roi = roi.reshape(1,28,28,1)
    

    cv2.imshow('frame', copy)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 13:
        break
        

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i am getting this error

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 90000 into shape (1,28,28,1)

Comment: A shape of `(1,28,28,1)` will result in `1*28*28*1 = 784` element in total. While you have an 1D array with 90000 elements. 90000 elements 1d  array can't be reshaped to an n-d array of 784 elements.

Comment: so what will be the solution ? @BrandyBerry

Comment: The reshaped "roi" wouldn't be used in your code anyway.

Comment: but i am reshaping it to pass it to a model. which expect the given shape @MichaelButscher

Comment: You probably want to resize it first. To do this you must take the image returned by "cv2.resize"

Comment: i resized it. in the 5th line in while loop @MichaelButscher

Comment: You must take the image **returned** by "cv2.resize"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224108/discussion-between-hamza-s-and-michael-butscher).